# Cannot able to find contacts/form.phtml in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.4, magento-1.5

i wanted to add some extra texts in my contact us form page(Default Magento). I googled it out and found [this tutorial](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/contact-form-in-magento/). When i tried to go that path then it i cannot able to find that file.Does anybody knows what's the reason behind of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check it in your custom theme's template folder if you don't have contacts folder over there then its in your base/default/template folder.

If thats the case copy it inside your custom theme folder as well as copy also the contacts.xml to your custom theme folder to ensure the theme fallback.

Comment: Thanks dude, your answer really helped me. I have founded it in the base/default/template folder... Thanks for your reply:)

Comment: @OhWhatANoob welcome ;-) Make sure you don't edit it inside the base theme folder. Instead of it copy it inside your custom theme / package and dow hat do you want, to ensure the Magento's theme fallback principle.